# How do you load this 8mm camera?

Tags: film, film-cameras

Where is the film gate?

How can I put film in this camera correctly?

[image]

[image]

It’s a Carena Variogon Zoomex. It’s not Super 8, it’s double 8mm.

---

Update. The [answer by Alan Marcus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102337/11586) got me thinking and taking a harder look. And sure, there *is* a little black film gate I missed among the black. I took a picture with flash on and edited the curves to make it stand out:

[image]

Comment: Were none of the videos on YouTube any help, no?

Comment: @osullic, you jest, but I will look there. Didn't occur to me that Marjorie the all-knowing trash heap might be that extensive.

Comment: Genuinely curios. You're a veteran SE user. There's Video.Se and Phote.SE. What led you to photo for this question over video?

Comment: @Hueco, I was thinking photography in general, like including film photography. Didn't even know there was a video SE. Thanks! Looking at video.SE now, it looks very heavy with post processing, scanning and such and mostly in the digital domain. Not much there on film. Nothing on Super8. Here there seems to be about 100 questions on Super8.

Comment: @Hueco I do think it's unclear. Being pedantic, film (the tangible strip of light-sensitive emulsion) and video (the electronic method for encoding moving images, potentially on magnetic tape) are arguably entirely distinct. Photography includes still photography and film photography. The film industry is synonymous with the movie industry. That's also arguably distinct from video. It's all a bit nebulous.

Comment: @osullic, by the way I found 4 or so Youtube videos, admiring the beauty of the camera, but not showing how to load it. :)

Comment: Wikipedia defines video as "an **electronic** medium for the recording, copying, playback, broadcasting, and display of moving visual media" [emphasis mine]. Personally, I think this question belongs on the non-existent cinematography.stackexchange.com. Or we could stop being so strict ourselves, and just allow these kinds of questions here, and handle it all with tags - isn't that what tags are for?

Comment: @osullic sounds like a great q for meta. As a film junkie (talking of the still photo film), I wouldn't mind having the 8mm film guys hangin' round here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double 8 movie film --- The first successful motion picture system was an invention of Thomas Edison. His system used 35mm wide long rolls of film. To transport the film through the camera smoothly, the film was punched on the left and right edges with holes (sprocket holes) that engaged with gears in the film transport mechanism.

Movies and 35mm wide film became popular. Movie cameras that accepted 35mm long rolls were big and cumbersome.  Kodak and others soon introduced smaller systems using 16mm wide film. 
Next, smaller cameras were designed especially for amateur movie photographers (home movies). These systems (you have one) accepted 16mm wide rolls of film. The film is rolled up on a flanged spool (reel) that accepted a 25 foot length of film.

The camera is supplied with an empty film reel. To load, this empty reel is moved to the take-up side of the camera. In subdued light, a new roll of 16mm film is unwrapped and placed in the receiving supply side of the camera. This special film featured a jet black backing called a “rem-ject”. This opaque backing protects the underlying film in the rolls from accidental exposure to light. The photographer threads the film from the supply roll to the take-up roll following the film path, which is specified by arrows engraved inside of the camera.

Once the new roll of film is threaded, the back is closed. Now the photographer begins to shoot movies. In just about 5 minutes of operation, the 25 foot long roll will be exposed. The entire 25 feet of film has now been re-spooled on what was an empty take-up reel.

Now the photographer must pause, open the camera back, remove the take-up reel with its exposed film, turn the reel over, and reinsert this reel in the supply positon. Now the photographer threads this film again. Once the camera is loaded for the second time, the photographer continues shooting for about 5 minutes.

Now the camera only exposes ½ of 16mm width on the first pass. The second pass exposes the other ½ of the width of the film. After the two passes through the camera, the film is sent to a photofinishing lab for developing. At the lab, the film is developed.

After the film is developed, the lab places the 25 foot long roll into a slitting machine. This machine slits the roll down the middle making two rolls of 8mm wide -- each 25 feet in length. The two halves are spliced together making a finished roll of movie film 50 feet long. At home the family enjoys about 10 minutes of home moves.

Because the loaded film is actually 16mm wide, this system is called “double 8”

Comment: I don't know why, but your exposé made me take a harder look at my camera. Maybe I got to thinking about how small the film gate must be.  And sure, there *is* a little black film gate in there hiding in the black metal! I feel like a fool now, but now I know how to load my camera... it's just as easy as it looks.

Comment: @Prof.Falken how about making a YouTube video showing how to do it? ;)

Comment: @osullic, I might! It will require me to get one of these new-fangled privacy invading google accounts, but I guess I can take one for the team. Alas, I also need to get some double 8mm film first. It seems my stock of 16mm double perforated film will not work though, so I must get some double 8mm, probably Adox are the only ones still making it? ( http://www.filmshooting.com/scripts/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17871 )